# How to create a countdown to Christmas

Tags: java

I have been trying to create a code that will countdown to Christmas for an android app.

This is what I have so far.

```
      Calendar thatDay = Calendar.getInstance();
      thatDay.setTime(new Date(0)); /* reset */
      thatDay.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 25);
      thatDay.set(Calendar.MONTH, 11); // 0-11 so 1 less
      thatDay.set(Calendar.YEAR, 2014);

      Calendar today = Calendar.getInstance();


     while (true)
     {


     long diff = thatDay.getTimeInMillis() - today.getTimeInMillis();
     long diffSec = diff / 1000;

     long days = diffSec / SECONDS_IN_A_DAY;
     long secondsDay = diffSec % SECONDS_IN_A_DAY;
     long seconds = secondsDay % 60;
     long minutes = (secondsDay / 60) % 60;
     long hours = (secondsDay / 3600); // % 24 not needed

  }
```

However, when I try to loop it, it generates too much output. How can I display the code updating every second?

Please help!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best if you use a ScheduledExecutorService, which repeats until it reaches the destination time.
Its advantage that it does not use your processor time between the printouts.

```
    final ScheduledExecutorService service = new ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor(1);
    final Calendar thatDay = new GregorianCalendar(2014, 11, 25);
    final Calendar today = Calendar.getInstance();
    service.schedule(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            long diff = thatDay.getTimeInMillis() - today.getTimeInMillis();
            long diffSec = diff / 1000;
            long days = diffSec / SECONDS_IN_A_DAY;
            long secondsDay = diffSec % SECONDS_IN_A_DAY;
            long seconds = secondsDay % 60;
            long minutes = (secondsDay / 60) % 60;
            long hours = (secondsDay / 3600); // % 24 not needed
            if (diff > 0) {
                ses2.schedule(this, 1, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
            }
        }
    }, 1, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
```

Answer (score 1):

Your loop

```
while (true) {
    ...
}
```

Never terminates, because you have no `break;` within it.

Instead, try a `for` loop:

```
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

SimpleDateFormat f = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
Date xmas = f.parse("2014-12-25");
for (long i = System.currentTimeMillis(); i < xmas.getTime(); i += TimeUnit.HOURS.toMillis(1)) { 
    long hours = TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toHours(xmas.getTime() - i);
    // do something with hours
}
```

This loops by hours until xmas, but you could change that quite easily.

Note the use of the [TimeUnit](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/TimeUnit.html) class instead of lots lines of math.

Comment: even after Christmas ;)

Comment: Minor typo, `i < xmas.getTine()` Sharp objects are dangerous in java.

Comment: @compass yes, I sometines mistype when thumbing code on my iPhone. Fixed, thx.

Comment: Thanks Bohemian! I am a total noob at Java! I have tried entering the code, but the compiler is having difficulty running it. any ideas? Thanks!